# Pointer initialization/dereferencing

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

What is the difference between

```
int(*a)[5];
int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
i = 0;
a = &b;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d\n", *(*a+i));
```

and

```
int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int *y = b;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d\n", *y+i);
```

Both snippets produce same output but I dont understand what is the difference in initialization?
How is

```
int *y = b;
```

different  to

```
int(*a)[5];
```

How to explain this kind of dereferencing?

```
printf("%d\n", *(*a+i));
```

Comment: First code is a pointer to an array of int, second example is Just an int pointer, pointing to an element inside an array, first example accesses same memory location but from an extra pointer level. `*a+1` is a pointer, dereference one more time to get the actual pointed integer. First example `*a+i` = `b+i` = `b[i]`, second example `y=b` = `&b[0]`, and `y+i` = `b[i]`

Comment: `*y+i` should be `*(y+i)`. The only reason you're getting the expected output is because the array contains sequential numbers. Change it to `{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}` and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: @AR7CORE thanks for answering this basic question.  What I dont understand is where does pointer to an array of int point to, what memory location. I can visualize pointer to an int but not for pointer to an array of ints.

Comment: Mistake un first comment: First example `*a+i` = `b+i` and `*(b+i)` = `b[i]`, since `*a=b` we have `*(*a+i))` = `*(b+i)`

Comment: `b` is a constant address to the first element of the array, `b` equals `&b[0]` by definition. `a` points to the address of `b`, `*a` = `b` and `**a` = `*b` = `b[0]`

Comment: Try and print size of `*a` and `*y`

Comment: By doing *y = b, array b decays to a pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

In your second code snippet

```
int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int *y = b;
```

in the declaration of the pointer `y` the array designator `b` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. The above declaration is equivalent to

```
int *y = &b[0];
```

Dereferencing the pointer `y` you will get the first element of the array of the type `int`.

Try the following demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int *y = b;

    printf( "sizeof( *y ) = %zu, *y = %d\n", sizeof( *y ), *y );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
sizeof( *y ) = 4, *y = 1
```

Thus in this for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d\n", *y+i);
```

you just outputting the value of the first element of the array `b` plus the value of the variable `i`. That is actually the loop does not output elements of the array `b` because they even are not accessed except the first element of the array..

If you want to output elements of the array you need to write

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d\n", *( y+i ));
```

It is the same as to write

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d\n", y[i] );
```

because the subscript operator is evaluated like (the C Standard, 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

In your first code snippet

```
int(*a)[5];
int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
i = 0;
a = &b;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d\n", *(*a+i));
```

the pointer `a` is declared as a pointer to array of the type `int[5]`. So dereferencing the pointer you get an array of the type `int[5]`.

Consider the following demonstration program,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
     int(*a)[5];
     int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    printf( "sizeof( *a ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *a ) );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
sizeof( *a ) = 20
```

In this for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d\n", *(*a+i));
```

the expression `*a` yields the pointed array `b` that used in the expression  `*a + i` is converted to pointer to its first element. To make it clear you could rewrite the for loop the following way

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int *p = *a;
    printf("%d\n", *(p + i));
}
```

That is in this declaration

```
    int *p = *a;
```

the array obtained by dereferencing the pointer  `a` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element according to the first provided quote from the C Standard..

Consider one more example. Let's assume that you have a two-dimensional array like for example

```
int b[2][5] =
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4,  5 },
    { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } 
};
```

As it was pointed out above the array used in expressions with rare exception is converted to pointer to its initial (first) element.
The type of elements of the array is `int[5]`. So you can declare a pointer like

```
int ( *a )[5] = b;
```

In this case to output the array you can write for example

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", *( *a + j ) );
    }

    ++a;
}
```

After this statement

```
++a;
```

the pointer `a` will point to the second element of the array `b` that is to its second "row" of the type `int[5]` due to the pointer arithmetic..

And again this declaration

```
int ( *a )[5] = b;
```

is equivalent to

```
int ( *a )[5] = &b[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Now I finally get it!

Answer (score 1):

Almost a side note, but some of the code is incorrect.

Referring to the code below ...

Note that the first snippet, which I'll call `foo` is correct.

But, the second snippet which I'll call `bar` is *incorrect*. It only works [serendipitously] because the `b` array is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` (i.e. in sorted order).

If the `b` array is *not* sorted, then `bar` will *not* print the correct order. This is because `*y + i` must be `*(y + i)`

For `*y + i`, the value fetched for *all* loop iterations is `b[0]` to which we add the value of `i`. To use array/index syntax, we are doing: `y[0] + i`

What we want is to fetch: `b[0] b[1] ... b[4]`

The corrected version is in `baz`. So, we use `*(y + i)`. In array/index syntax, this is `y[i]`.

---

Here is the code that illustrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if SORTED
int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
#else
int b[5] = { 5, 4, 1, 2, 3 };
#endif

void
foo(void)
{
    int (*a)[5];
    a = &b;

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("foo: %d\n", *(*a + i));
}

void
bar(void)
{
    int *y = b;

    printf("\n");

// NOTE/BUG: "*y + i" is incorrect -- see baz
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("bar: %d\n", *y + i);
}

void
baz(void)
{
    int *y = b;

    printf("\n");

// NOTE/FIX: correct fix for bar
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("baz: %d\n", *(y + i));
}

int
main(void)
{

    foo();
    bar();
    baz();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
foo: 5
foo: 4
foo: 1
foo: 2
foo: 3

bar: 5
bar: 6
bar: 7
bar: 8
bar: 9

baz: 5
baz: 4
baz: 1
baz: 2
baz: 3
```